# How do I programmatically invoke an event?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I am creating a C# Windows Mobile application that I need to programmatically invoke the click event on a Button.

I have looked at the Button class and do not see a way to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might consider changing your design: at least move the logic from button1_Click handler somewhere else so that you'll be able to invoke it from wherever you want.

Comment: Unluckily this seems the only answer for the Windows Mobile platform. I wish MS would add something that would allow this.

Zzub

Comment: I cannot think of any sane reason why anybody would want to click buttons programatically.

Comment: If you have a hardware button that you want to click the button.  That seems like an obvious one.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnButtonClick();
    }

    private void OnButtonClick()
    {

    }
```

Then you can call your `OnButtonClick()` wherever you need to.

Comment: Nope, PerformClick doesn't exist in the CF.

Comment: button1_Click is still just a method.  You can call it directly.

Comment: Yes, you CAN, but I think it's a lot cleaner to have a method that describes what you want to to, rather than calling button1_Click(null,new EventArgs());

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer you were probably looking for:::

You might just call the code you want to run, move the meat of the code outside the OnClick handling method. The OnClick method could fire that method the same as your code.

Answer (score 1):

The Control class, from which Button inherits, has the OnClick method, which invokes the Click event.  Using reflection, you can call this method, even though it is declared protected.  For instance, I created the following extension method:

```
public static void PerformClick(this Control value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        var methodInfo = value.GetType().GetMethod("OnClick", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        methodInfo.Invoke(value, new object[] { EventArgs.Empty });
    }
```

Although, this may be regarded as a dirty hack...

Answer (score 0):

Anything that prevents you from simply invoking the method that handles the onClick event?

Comment: Why the down vote? I can read some other answers that say the same thing and don't have down votes...

Comment: Yea, I don't get the downvote either. Although, I wouldn't advise calling the button1_Click event directly. Something about it just doesn't feel "clean" to me. +1 to balance out though.

Comment: @Sergio: I haven't voted you down, but your answer can be read with a very nasty "Why haven't you thought of the easiest thing?" way, which is not very "helpful", which is what a vote measures.

Comment: Sorry if i sounded nasty, that was not my intention... What i really meant was if there was anything that would prevent him from doing that, like company policies, etc.. And at the same time point out a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the added event handler function as:

```
someControl_EventOccured(someControl, new EventArgs());
```

This works when the control's event argument `e` is not used inside the handler function, and mostly it's not used.